# Proving that a bijection exists

Tags: analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f$ be a bijective function from $A$ to $B$. Let $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ . Prove that there exists a bijection $g$ defined from $A$ to  $B$ such that $g(x)=y$ .

Here is my solution but i don't know if it is correct.
Assume that $f(x) \neq y$ , because if they were equal taking $g$ the same bijection as $f$ would work.

Since $f$ is a bijection  we have $|A|=|B|$ and there exists $x_1 \in A$ and $y_1 \in B $ such that $f(x_1)=y$ and $f(x)=y_1$ 
Now taking  $g(a)=f(a)$ if $a \neq x_1$ or$ x$ ,   and  $g(x)=y $ and 
    $g(x_1)=y_1$ completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof is correct. A similar proof shows that if $f$ is any function, one-to-one, or onto, then $g$ is any function, one-to-one, or onto respectively, with $g(x)=y$.